# How do I allow a user to create related accounts and edit their content?

Tags: 7, users

Here is what I'm trying to achieve: The site has users who can add items to their wish lists (a wish item is one node); I'd like to enable these users to create subusers that are related to them and create wish items for them.
For example,  I'm a user, I added items that I wish I would have, but I want to create a profile for my kids, and add items to their wish list; in this way, I could share those lists with their uncle.

How can I achieve something like this in Drupal 7?

In the case somebody is going to suggest the [Subuser](https://drupal.org/project/subuser) module, I tried it, but I got a bunch of database errors just installing and enabling it.

The kind of answer I'm hoping for is a sort of overview of how to achieve something like this, just to push me in the right direction. I'm not expecting code.